# Pandas list of JSON element to python array

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

| Store | matches |
| --- | --- |
| Murphy's | [{'domain': 'murphyscolumbus.com', 'location': 'Columbus, OH'}, {'domain': 'murphystampa.com', 'location': 'Tampa, FL'}] |
| Bill's | [{'domain': 'billsdallas.com', 'location': 'Dallas, TX'}, {'domain': 'billsorlando.com', 'location': 'Orlando, FL'}] |

What I want is a dataframe like so:

| Store | domains |
| --- | --- |
| Murphy's | ['murphyscolumbus.com', 'murphystampa.com'] |
| Bill's | ['billsdallas.com','billsorlando.com'] |

I'm hoping for something less computationally expensive than something like a for loop that steps through as the dataframe is *quite* large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply literal_eval if necessary
df["matches"] = df["matches"].apply(literal_eval)

df["domains"] = df.pop("matches").apply(lambda x: [d["domain"] for d in x])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Store                                  domains
0  Murphy's  [murphyscolumbus.com, murphystampa.com]
1    Bill's      [billsdallas.com, billsorlando.com]
```